# Java (jsp) redirect with HTTP POST data?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a system that allows guest logins via a guest account. I cannot modify the source code of the system, but I *can* add my own JSP files. I am implementing an anti-phishing login process and don't want to expose the real login URL in my HTML. Instead of creating a "guest" link that posts directly to the real login URL, I would like to forward the user to my own JSP that redirects their request to the real login.

This means I need to send POST data do the real login script in my redirect. If possible, I do not want to use the HttpClient class to open a connection and do the posting. The system does several redirects of its own after posting to the login script. Which means I would have to handle them myself if I used HttpClient.

So, is it possible to do a `response.sendRedirect()` and include POST data to the redirect URL?

Comment: The solution shown below is what you want, but to clarify your question... no, you can't include POST data in the redirection. You just send a redirect back to the client and it's up to the client to repost the data to the new URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `forward` the complete request to the other controller (servlet/JSP) and let the other controller process and respond.

From the [Java Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29):

> ```
> forward(ServletRequest request,
>         ServletResponse response)
>         throws ServletException,
>                IOException
> ```
>
> Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server. This method allows one servlet to do preliminary processing of a request and another resource to generate the response.